# Is there a way to set the angle mode to degrees in python math?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

Is there a way to set the angle mode to *degrees* in python math?

You know that in python, the trigonometric functions are default in *radians* mode

```py
from math import sin, radians
print(sin(radians(30)))
```

When I work with *degrees*, it seems redundant to keep typing `radians(...)`.

```py
from math import sin, radians

def sin2(degrees):
    return sin(radians(degrees))

## or
sin2 = lambda degrees: sin(radians(degrees))

print(sin2(30))
```

It seems fine to just define functions like those,
but, does anyone know a better way of doing this? Setting the mode in math maybe?

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution than to define your own functions.

Comment: You can, for example though patching modules on import, however it's complicated and overkill to this senario

Comment: I feel like the python documentation explicitly says the parameters are in radians. There is no "mode". Wherever you enter degrees, just immediately convert there.

Comment: Angle modes are typically features of hand-held scientific calculators. Trig functions in programming languages almost universally work in radians. I suggest that defining your own functions that take arguments in degrees is likely to be more confusing to readers than doing an explicit conversion on each call.

Answer (score 1):

A pure setting in `math`, as far I know there isn't any. However, we can wrap their trigonometric functions to accepts angles in degrees.

```
import math

def trig_wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [math.radians(arg) if isinstance(arg, (int, float)) else arg for arg in args]
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

for func_name in ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']:
    setattr(math, func_name, trig_wrapper(getattr(math, func_name)))

print(math.sin(90))
print(math.cos(0))
```

Personally, I won't recommend it, and I prefer to define new functions.

Comment: Ok, I guess that is something to try.